# How to ignore tags on beautifulsoup4 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parser

I'm working on a new project and I have some issues.

My problem as like that.

```
<div class="news">
      <p class="breaking">  </p>
      ...
<p> i need to pull here. </p>
```

but class = "breaking" is not let me to do it. I want to ignore the class "breaking" and pull the `<p>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, `class=''` would do with `find_all` or `findAll`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="news">
      <p class="breaking">  </p>
      ...
<p> i need to pull here. </p>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all('p', class_=''))
print(soup.findAll(True, {'class': ''}))
```

#### Output

```
[<p> i need to pull here. </p>]
[<p> i need to pull here. </p>]
```